# Check if an object is a specific class and conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, swift3, protocols, mixins

Not sure if this is a weird way to do this but in Swift 3 I want to check if an object is a `UIViewController` and conforms to my protocol `Transitionable`. I have:

```
guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to),
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
    let toTransitionable = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) as? Transitionable,
    let fromTransitionable = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) as? Transitionable
else {
    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    return
}
```

But i was hoping I could get and object that is both `UIViewController` and `Transitionable` for the to and from.
i tried `let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) as? Transitionable as? UIViewController` but that keeps it as just a `UIViewController`

I also tried:

```
extension Transitionable where Self: UIViewController {
    var viewController: UIViewController { return self }
}
```

But i get the error: `'Transitionable' is not a subtype of 'UIViewController'` when i call `toTransitionable.viewController` e.g.

```
transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toTransitionable.viewController.view)
```

I understand we can do `as? (UIViewController & Transitionable)` in Swift 4 but this project is going to be in Swift 3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this might help but try:

```
if let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) as? UIViewController{
    if let _ = toViewController as? Transitionable{
       print("conforms to protocol")
    }
}

if let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) as? UIViewController{
    if let _ = fromViewController as? Transitionable{
       print("conforms to protocol")
    }
}
```

Or, if you want it in only one variable that is both

You can create a new class that extends UIViewController and implement the protocol Transitionable.

Something like:

```
class YourNewViewControllerClass : UIViewController,Transitionable{
    //implements your  Transitionable methods
}
```

After:

```
if let viewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) as? YourNewViewControllerClass{
       //success
}
```

Comment: i was hoping I could get and object that is both `UIViewController` and `Transitionable`